# How can I reference a page in another pdf, which I have no control over?

Tags: cross-referencing, pdftex, pdf

I want to reference a specific page in another pdf document. There is also a bookmark on that page, which I could use.

However, I have no control over the other document, and maybe it wasn't even created with Tex.

Is there a way to extract labels from the file that I could use with `\hyperref` or `xr`, or which other packages or commands could I use?

Comment: Usually you refer to other (external) sources by citing them, e.g. `\cite`. As far as i understood, `\ref` is really made only for inernal referencing.

Comment: This would be nice for referencing in large document packs.

Comment: The beginning of your question seems to imply you know the page you want to open to;  Adobe's documentation at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf has examples of opening pdf documents via URL (I would guess a "file://" would work too).  So now the issue is to create a clickable URL in your document.  I am puzzled by the second part of your question:  Even if you extracted all the labels in the file, how would you know which specific label to target?

Comment: Well, I could try them all or at least hope that they are named somewhat reasonable so that I can identify the one I need. That link you provided mentions "named destinations", that looks promising. I'll see if I can extract those from the document.

Comment: The hyperref package is not worked in latex to give reference in latex of external.pdf document

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the external PDF is generated with `pdflatex` without labels or with another program as LibreOffice, you can use `\href` of package `hyperref` with the option `[page=x]`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Some text.  
\href[page=4]{external.pdf}{See page 4 of the external PDF} 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this work with Acrobat Reader but not with others as Evince, for example. This is a problem of the viewer, not the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 4):

user1823664's documentation link gave me another lead.

In Acrobat, under `View > Show/Hide > Navigation Pane > Destinations` one can find a list of destinations in the document. They can be referenced via

```
\href{external.pdf#thedestination}{See other stuff of the external PDF}
```